# Give new value to variable recursively

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have something like:

```
\pgfmathsetmacro{\radius}{2}
```

and inside a `\foreach` I'm trying to define a new value for `\radius` to be half the size of the previous but using

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\radius{\radius/2}
```

isn't working...

Any sugestions on how to define a value recursively?

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you have to expand the old value first, but without seeing any code...

Comment: A complete example of what you're doing would be nice, there might well be some other way of solving it.

Comment: The `\foreach` macro supports the key `remember` which can be handy in this case; an example would be very useful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside a `foreach` the code is scoped which means when one spin is completed the value returns to its original value. You can basically do a global let

```
\pgfmathparse{\radius/2}
\global\let\radius=\pgfmathresult
```